# How to do a multiline comment in Julia?

Tags: julia, comments

My Google search at first only lead me to a massive discussion thread on github (https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/69). While certainly insightful and interesting, I think it is convenient for many to have this question answered immediately on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Multiline comments can be written by putting `#=` before the comment and `=#` after the comment. Like so

```
#=
enter comment here
=#
```

Note that these are nestable as well.

Comment: Also, you can use them inline: `atan(1 #=hello=#,0)`